# How to increase the spacing between the Android keyboard and the focus field?

Tags: android, keyboard, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I would like to increase the spacing between the Android keyboard and the focus field to display the informational text just below the field while it is being filled. Is this a variable to add in the manifest?

Comment: You can't control that with any configuration, perhaps you could do it by adjusting your vertical scroll offset as needed upon focus.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information.